# Eliminate redundancy from if loop

Tags: design-patterns

how would you write the following code:

```
if(Conditon 1){
            # code block 1...

            // another if condition
            if($device!=null){
                # code block 2...
            }else{
                # <code block X>
            }
}else{
            # <code block X>
}
```

So here `# <code block X>` is same at two places, how can I eliminate the redundancy?

Comment: move it to a separate function and call that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General approach: find out the preconditions for each block to be executed:

- code block **1**: `Condition1`
- code block **2**: `Condition1 && $device!=null`
- code block **x**: `!Condition1 || !($device!=null)`

The precondition for block 2 is the opposite of the precondition for block x: `!(a && b) = !a || !b`, so they're suited to go into an `if-else`:

```
if(Conditon1){
    # code block 1...
}
if(Conditon1 && $device!=null){
    # code block 2...
} else {
    # <code block X>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Conditon 1){
            # code block 1...

            // another if condition
            if($device!=null){
                # code block 2...
            }
}

if (!Condition1 || $device==null){
    # <code block X>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//A variable to store true/false
var a = true;
if(Conditon 1){
  # code block 1...    
  // another if condition
    if($device!=null){
     # code block 2...
   a =false;
   }
}
 if(a){
 # <code block X>
}
```